# Using wp_localize_script inside template page to transfer var from php to js

Tags: javascript, page-template, wp-localize-script

I have been looking for a help on the forum, but nothing matches really my problem.

I am actually trying to use [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) with Wordpress. My problem is that where I create my gallery image (a template page in a child theme) I need to pass the image's urls that I got dynamically from previous page to js file to create my gallery image with the option propose by bxslider. (In particular with [thumbnail](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2))

To pass variables from php to js, I normally use wp_localize_script in function.php or a plugin but not a template page. And in this case I can't even enqueue my script.

How can I pass variables from template page to javascript file with dynamic variable (so impossible for me to pass through function.php)

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it ! :)

The problem was that I add my function to localize and enqueue my script at the end of the page with the function itself, after wordpress loop. So I finally add the function before to get the header and this time, I can pass variables normally.

(*I already register my script in **function.php***)

**Code before (wrong) :**

```
[...Code...]
function pass_var_to_js() {
    global $my_variable;
    wp_localize_script('script_name','send_var', array( $my_variable ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('script_name');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pass_var_to_js');
```

**Code after (right) :**

```
[...Code...]
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pass_var_to_js');
get_header();
[...Code...]
function pass_var_to_js() {
    global $my_variable;
    wp_localize_script('script_name','send_var', array( $my_variable ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('script_name');
}
```

I hope that it could help someone !